# How to get value from nested xpath in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test an application with Selenium and Java, what I want to achieve, is the following.

Click on a select box (which works) and then select from a multiple selectoption the one equaling my input. So if my Feature file says dog I want from the options dog to be selected.

My code to select the option after opening the selectbox looks like this:

```
WebElement xyz = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//*[@id='xyz']/div[2]/ul/li[text()='%s']",selectElement)));
```

If I delete /li every option is selected in my console in the browser, so I thought with `/li[text()='%s']` I could dynamically set the option name. But I am getting a nosuchelementexcetion, what could be my mistake? If i right 1 instead of `text() = '%s'` I am being able to select the option

Answer (score 0):

For the select box, you need to create a `Select` object which targets the select box and then select by value to get the item you want to select. For example:

```
Select drpDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(//pathToElement]")));

drpDown.selectByValue(selectElement);
```

Hope this helps :)